# Installing multiple php modules with ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to install multiple php modules with ansible

Here is the example of tasks:

```
- name: debug php modules
  debug: msg="{{ php_version }}-{{ item }}"
  with_items: php_modules

- name: php modules/extensions are installed
  yum:
    state=present
    name="{{ php_version }}-{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ php_modules }}"
  when: php_modules is defined
```

and the actual variables defined:

```
  vars:
    php_version: php56u
    php_modules:
      - intl
      - pdo
```

The playbook fails with `"No Package matching 'pdo' found available, installed or updated"`

I tried with `with_items: php_modules` and couldn't get it to work properly. It is strange because debug above works every time:

```
ok: [server-1] => (item=intl) => {
    "item": "intl",
    "msg": "php56u-intl"
}

ok: [server-1] => (item=pdo) => {
    "item": "pdo",
    "msg": "php56u-pdo"
}
```

A strange issue. I might be missing something very simple here?

Comment: Shouldn't this rather be `php-pdo-version`? Does a `yum install php56u-pdo` work for you? I have not the right repo installed to make it work with this version but I only can get it working in this form: `yum install php-pdo-5.4.16`

Comment: @udondan php56u is IUS repo package name notation. What is strange here is that debug properly forms the string but not the yum module?

Comment: I think this is rather a problem of the yum module or just s strange way how yum itself responds. There should be no way how Ansible itself could do anything wrong with passing the expected string to the yum module. But you can test it yourself. Register the output of the yum task and show the result with a debug task. You should see the parameters passed to yum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @udondan for the hint about debugging output of yum module. That helped a lot! It turns out ansible yum module tries to install everything at once and hence the list becomes something like `"php56u-intl,pdo"` instead of `"php56u-intl,php56u-pdo"` (hence the difference with the way "debug" module treats it, debug runs multiple times for each item but yum puts them all together).
The bug/feature/limitation was actually reported here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/5871

The trick, as one of the comments in the issue lists is to use "join", which forces yum module to run each item separately:

```
- name: php modules/extensions are installed
  yum:
    state=present
    name={{ item|join('-') }}
  with_nested:
    - php_version
    - php_modules
  when: php_modules is defined
```

This is potentially the only way to do it until ansible yum module adds an option "one_by_one_install_please_please_please: true/false"